# this train terminates at x

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I live in Denmark and when they want to announce the destination of the train in English, they say

> "This train terminates at x".

Is it correct English?

Whenever I hear it, I have a feeling that the train is going to explode

Comment: I've not heard it phrased that way on American transportation.  I usually hear, "The destination (or final destination) of this train is x," or sometimes the shorter, "this is an/the x train."  "Terminates" would be understood, but like you, we'd probably feel a bit weird about the phrasing.

Comment: Absolutely correct (BrE) -- and the journey terminates at a *terminus*.

Comment: In the UK we usually just say *This is the X train*, or *This train goes to X* when giving information at some point *other* than X. You hear *This train terminates **here*** on the train and/or platform, because everyone needs to be told to get off. You'd only really care that the train *terminated* at X before you got there if you wanted to make sure that was really the last stop, so you'd be in no danger of sleeping past your station.

Comment: At least with California trains (*both* of them. Ha! I jest. But only slightly ...)  they usually say "this is the final stop" and never "terminus".  I suspect "terminus" would upset a lot of folks who didn't know what it meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not something that ordinary people say. But it's certainly something that the announcements on British trains regularly say. I would regard it as a kind of "[officialese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Officialese)".

Comment: It's hard to remember details that far back, but for years I went to school by train, where half the departures actually terminated in my school's town. I definitely recall that *during* those years they started using the PA on the train itself to announce the fact of the impending terminus as we were pulling in and braking. But I'm pretty sure it was just *The train on platform 3 is for X* when being announced at my boarding station. You as a passenger don't care where the train *terminates* - just that it's going where you want to go. But platform staff just want you out *at* the terminus.

Comment: I also hear "This **service** terminates at xyz".

Comment: It's a specific branch of officialese that we might call "train talk".

Comment: The recordings on the Airedale line, which have persisted through at least three train operators, inform you that "This is Leeds. The train terminates here. Please take all your belongings when you leave". The particularly annoying bit is that this plays _before the doors have closed at the previous stop_.

Answer (score 2):

The phrasing

> This train terminates at x.

where **X** is the name of the last stop, is correct English.

The phrase is used often on the London Underground

> [**This train terminates at** *Finchley Road*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyiZAXkIhCM&t=0m8s)  *(voice announcement)*
>   [**This train terminates at** *Morden via Bank*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uL5N54peEkY)  *(sign announcement)*

[*(How many animals can you see?)*](https://www.google.com/search?q=animals+in+the+london+tube+map&client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&imgil=qTEgK-MxWUsyYM%253A%253BnhqgtO5QV_iGBM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.lahistoriaconmapas.com%25252Fatlas%25252Ftube-map%25252Fanimals-london-underground-map.htm&source=iu&pf=m&fir=qTEgK-MxWUsyYM%253A%252CnhqgtO5QV_iGBM%252C_&usg=__QZAA_XsnrtSJnFT-vUuvAgG-qGA%3D&biw=1185&bih=795&ved=0ahUKEwizxIn8m47QAhUm6oMKHUuOARcQyjcIRg&ei=bAgcWLPeAabUjwTLnIa4AQ#imgrc=_)

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [clarksbury.com](http://www.clarksbury.com/cdl/maps/tube87.jpg))</sub>


An alternative phrase is

> [**This train is for** *Richmond, Brighouse*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoYWVVBWLTk)

Comment: to expand on your answer a little,  it is particularly important to know where the Underground train terminates in the case if the Northern Line. The ones that terminate at Edgware Road take a very route than those at High Barnet.https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Northern_Line.svg#mw-jump-to-license

Comment: Edgware. Edgware Road isn't on the Northern line.

Comment: @Sarriesfan [Edgware Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgware_Road_tube_station_(Circle,_District_and_Hammersmith_%26_City_lines)) would be a very different stop than Edgware

Comment: Yes Edgware Rd and Eddware are different, duh.

Comment: My favorite is Mornington Crescent.

Answer (score 0):

If "X" is the final destination for that train, then the phrasing "This train terminates at X (Station)" is right, I think.